# Writing Python script to give multiple buffers of different sizes in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arcmap

I want to write a loop that will cause the output to be multiple buffer shapefiles.

For example, I want a circle buffer of 50ft, 100ft, 150ft, etc.

Can anyone help?

I'm new to this and am trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: I know there is a tool that can do this (Multiple Ring Buffer) but I want to know how to write a loop.

Answer (score 16):

The ArcGIS Resource Center has the [following sample script](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001p000000) demonstrating how to do multiple ring buffers using Python

```
# Name: MultipleRingBuffer_Example2.py
# Description: Create multiple buffers for the input features
# Author: ESRI

# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/data/airport.gdb"

# Set local variables
inFeatures = "schools"
outFeatureClass = "c:/output/output.gdb/multibuffer1"
distances = [10,20,30]
bufferUnit = "meters"

# Execute MultipleRingBuffer
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(inFeatures, outFeatureClass, distances, bufferUnit, "", "ALL")
```

---

Here's how to do it if you insist on having a **for loop**

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data" 

distances =[50, 100, 150]
for distance in distances:
    outfile = "C:/output/majorrdsBuffered%s" % distance  
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis("roads", outfile, distance, "FULL", "ROUND", "LIST", "Distance")
```

Comment: Would that for loop code not overwrite it's own outputs? It could be altered to say `out_file = "C:/output/majorrdsBuffered" + str(distance)` to put the buffersize in the filename.

Comment: arcpy.Buffer_analysis(clipoutfile, buffered + "_" + str(x) + ".shp", str(x)+" "+buff_unit) this is what I ended up doing as a call.

Comment: Did it work? Good to know. The file names are your call in the end.

Comment: Interesting! But what if I want the buffers to be on different layers e.g. 50 meters on roads, 100 meters on schools, 200 meters on bars?

Comment: @user37199 an answer to that is too long for comments. Why don't you post a separate question? :)